# Distribute and run a jar file with only our own custom Kotlin Classes

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I am using `gradle build` that generates an all-encompassing ueber-jar

```
<myproject>-<version>-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

with over 3700 classes in it.  Of these maybe thirty are project-specific custom classes.

While it would not be difficult to manually extract just the custom classes this leaves several desirable features:

1. a `gradle build` task to create the application-only jar?
2. a `gradle build` task to separately build the *boilerplate* jar
3. a `gradle run` task that would include both of those jars in its `classpath` as part of running a specified `kotlin` class containing a `main` entry point

The motivation likely is obvious: re-generating an entire ueber-jar *every time* is a drag on the iterative development cycle.

**Update** Here are the two tasks that would stand to benefit.

```
task runServer(type: JavaExec) {
    main ='org.naphi.ServerTest'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}

task runClient(type: JavaExec) {
    main ='org.naphi.SocketClientTest'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

Note that neither of them are working presently:

```
 $gradle runServer

> Task :runServer FAILED
Error: Could not find or load main class org.naphi.ServerTest
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.naphi.ServerTest
```

But that is probably a separate question about how to use a properly baked project `classpath` within a `gradle` task.

Comment: What are the remaining classes?  The Kotlin runtime?  Or from other libraries/frameworks?

Comment: Yes and yes. e.g. `org.intellij.*`,  `kotlin.*`  , `org.apache.commons.*` , `org.apache.http.*` and more